# Tooltips are not removed from DOM after destroy event

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When tooltip is active/focused and `destroy` event is called the tooltip gets opacity 0, but still clickable and its element still in the DOM.

The problem is reproduced in this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jeRub/):
When test button is clicked the tooltip gets "destroyed", but it's still in the DOM and blocks click events on the text input.

Is it normal behaviour? Any clean workarounds?

**UPD**: seems to be a known [**issue**](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10740)

Comment: @Dvir, it's a cross-browser issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about if you use `disable` instead of `destroy`?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeRub/1/)

Comment: Oh nice, I tried to disable **and** destroy before but it didn't work as expected. Your solution works just fine.

Comment: You might try to use that in addition to using the hide option, so that it actually hides on click, instead of having to move out... I tried to do that, but for some reason it didnt hide the popup :(

Comment: Well, to me, disable and destroy would pretty much have the same utility. Both will make it not show up again :) I like your workaround though

Comment: @PSL And you are applying the same code as a working version, so thats a patch/fix, not a workaround. Workaround is when you work around the issue... As we are doing with the `disable` ;)

Comment: I'm not saying you did, I'm just saying you are incorrect in stating that your answer is a workaround. Your answer is a fix, as you are applying the code that was applied to fix the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, There is a workaround. Remove `data-toggle="tooltip"` from your markup. That is what is causing tooltip to be displayed again. Because you still have the data attribute on the tooltip which bootstrap listens to. Your constructor in the js is enough, placing both the `data-*` for tooltip and tooltip constructor in JS is not necessary.

```
 <input id="testBtn" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Test"  title="Test Destroy Event"/>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4cHGe/)**

**Update**

it is a bug in older version of Bootstrap, So to fix it in older version you can remove the $tip element by grabbing it from Data.

```
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('bs.tooltip').$tip.remove(); //remove the tip element.
        $this.tooltip('destroy'); //destroy it now.
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zwjgX/)**

*Remember even if you disable the element, it still holds the data in the element, and the reference of the element inside the bootstrap for a possibility of later usage which is unnecessary*

Comment: Sorry, still the same issue in your demo.

Comment: Even if you disable it still holds the tooltip data on the element, means it doesn't destroy them when you no longed need it. So there should be a real workaround for this BS bug.

Comment: there's no tooltip data in your demo. I don't think you're correct.

Comment: @MaksimVi. I got the issue in BS code itself. It is a bug in the version you are using.. Upgrade to latest and they have fixed it.

Comment: No need, thanks, already found it (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10740)